# mybatis @Insert annotation for Mysql and H2 - need a way to use Point for mysql and ST_Point for H2

Tags: mybatis

I have an insert statement for Mybatis that's specified by an annotation and I need to have a different query in the insert based on the database H2 or MySQL - basically:

`INSERT POINT(#{lat}, #{lng}) INTO table` for mysql and `INSERT ST_POINT(#{lat}, #{lng}) INTO table` for H2.

How do I specify the database type for the annotation or how (generally) is this done using annotation configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 3.5.5, MyBaits supports `databaseId` in annotations.

With the following example, the first INSERT will be used for H2, the second one will be used for MySQL and the third one will be used for others (the SQL syntax may be invalid, but you get the idea).

```java
public interface YourMapper {
  @Insert(value = "INSERT ST_POINT(#{lat}, #{lng}) INTO table", databaseId = "h2")
  @Insert(value = "INSERT POINT(#{lat}, #{lng}) INTO table", databaseId = "mysql")
  @Insert(value = "INSERT INTO table VALUES (POINT(#{lat}, #{lng}))")
  int insert(YourParameter param);
}
```

You may also need to configure databaseIdProvider in the config.

```xml
<databaseIdProvider type="DB_VENDOR">
  <property name="H2" value="h2"/>
  <property name="MySQL" value="mysql"/>
</databaseIdProvider>
```

The same config for [mybatis-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/mybatis/spring-boot-starter) :

```java
@Bean
VendorDatabaseIdProvider vendorDatabaseIdProvider() {
  VendorDatabaseIdProvider databaseIdProvider = new VendorDatabaseIdProvider();
  Properties vendorProperties = new Properties();
  vendorProperties.put("H2", "h2");
  vendorProperties.put("MySQL", "mysql");
  databaseIdProvider.setProperties(vendorProperties);
  return databaseIdProvider;
}
```